# unable to use 'new WP_Query' in AJAX call

Tags: php, wp-query, ajax, query

I'm trying to create category filter for posts. I usually work with `get_posts` function but this time I need to keep pagination, that's why I'm trying to use `new WP_Query`.

I have successfully created AJAX solution that returns posts and display it, but seems like using `new WP_Query` breaks AJAX call.

Here's my code for AJAX:

```
(function($){
$(function() {
    $('.category-filter .filter a' ).click( function(e) {
        var category = $(this).data('id');
        var container = $('#main');
        if ( $( 'body' ).hasClass( 'blog' ) ) {
            var action = 'get_posts_from_category';
        } else if( $( 'body' ).hasClass( 'post-type-archive-event' ) ) {
            var action = 'get_events_from_category';
        }
        $(this).closest( '.category-filter' ).find( '.filter' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        $(this).parent().addClass( 'active' );
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_cat.url,
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                action: action,
                nonce: ajax_cat.nonce,
                category: category,
            },
            success: function( $data ) {
                container.html( $data );
            },
            error: function( error ) {
                console.log( error );
            }
        })
    })
});
})(jQuery);
```

And php action:

```
function get_posts_from_category() {
$category = $_POST['category'];

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$myquery = new WP_Query( $args );

if($myquery->have_posts()):
    while($myquery->have_posts()):
        $myquery->the_post();
        the_title();
        echo '<br>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
endif;

wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_posts_from_category', __NAMESPACE__ . '\get_posts_from_category' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_posts_from_category', __NAMESPACE__ . '\get_posts_from_category' );
```

Tried many variations and seems like `new WP_Query` is an issue here. Thanks for any advices.

Comment: if it breaks the call, how does it break the call? What is the error message in the PHP error log? Also can you fix the indenting in your code? `wp_reset_query` is for cleaning up after a `query_posts` call, you should be using `wp_reset_postdata` instead

Comment: I also see you chose to use the older admin ajax handler API rather than the newer REST API, what was the reason behind that? WP will create an endpoint for you at `/wp-json/wp/v2/events` that you can query that returns the posts as JSON with pagination etc and human readable error messages if you use `show_in_rest` when registering your post type, you shouldn't need to build your own AJAX handling code for this

Comment: it does not matter if `wp_reset_query` was or wasn't there, call was still broken. Error code is just 'Critical error on site...' nothing helpful.  I'm using `show_in_rest` for registering but I also tested this on regular posts and result was the same

Comment: There's nothing special about using WP_Query in AJAX. Your error log will contain the full details of the error, so you need to track that down. Your host will know where it is if you can't find it, or you can use WP_DEBUG_LOG: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log

Answer (score 2):

Just to clear this up for someone that might have similar problem, everything was find with query, the problem with this was Wordpress was looking for WP_Query class in namespace file, replacing `new WP_Query` with `new \WP_query` solved this problem :D thanks for help!

Comment: I have to say thanks, just like that all my problems were solved!

Comment: invested 2 hrs of mine to find this answer. :) Thanks for this.